# connect more input to micro from pc817

Tags: microcontroller, mplab

How to connect more input to a microcontroller?
I have 14 optocupler pc817 (1,2,3......,14):

```
connect all pins 4 together from 1st set of 7th pc817 to mc(E1)
connect pin 3 from  pc817 no.1 to mc(A0)
connect pin 3 from  pc817 no.2 to mc(A1)
connect pin 3 from  pc817 no.3 to mc(A2)
connect pin 3 from  pc817 no.4 to mc(A3)
connect pin 3 from  pc817 no.5 to mc(A4)
connect pin 3 from  pc817 no.6 to mc(A5)
connect pin 3 from  pc817 no.7 to mc(E0)
connect all pins 4 together from 2nd set of 7 pc817 to mc(E2)
connect pin 3 from  pc817 no.8  to mc(A0)
connect pin 3 from  pc817 no.9  to mc(A1)
connect pin 3 from  pc817 no.10 to mc(A2)
connect pin 3 from  pc817 no.11 to mc(A3)
connect pin 3 from  pc817 no.12 to mc(A4)
connect pin 3 from  pc817 no.13 to mc(A5)
connect pin 3 from  pc817 no.14 to mc(E0)
```

See this schematic:

[image]

How does the circuit work and how to write its code?

Answer (score 0):

You can look at it as a 2D matrix n times m, n sets of m optocouplers, in your case n=2 and m=7.

You can read only one set of 7 optocouplers at a time. To read both, you need in principle this sequence:

1. Set E1 "high" and E2 "low".
2. Read A0 to A5 and E0 for the first set.
3. Set E1 "low" and E2 "high".
4. Read A0 to A5 and E0 for the second set.

Now you have 14 bit values and you can process them.

This is called [time division multiplexing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplexing#Time-division_multiplexing), you have 2 time steps and 7 data bits per step.

The circuit works like this:

Only those transistors that have their collectors at "high" can conduct, if they are "on" via their respective LED. I would call them "enabled". If they are "on", the "high" level is readable on A0 to A5 and E0, respectively.

Any transistor with the collector at "low" cannot provide a "high". I would call it "disabled".

To avoid interfering feedback (or reverse) current to the "disabled" transistors, the diodes separate them.

Comment: Thank you.  You have simple code for this? And can i read  both switches connect to A0 at the same time??

Comment: StackOverflow is _not_ a code writing service, this is your task. If you have problems with it, feel free to post a new question that shows what you have so far and explains where you stumble. -- No, you cannot read both switches connected to A0 at the same time. How would you differentiate _which_ optocoupler is "high" or "low", if you have just one bit?

Comment: BTW, "Thank you" is better expressed by marking the answer. ;-)

Comment: I toled my doctor that.but he toled me not TDM teq. And if press 2 switches on A0 work . What about ADC?? I sugg. Use multiplexing ic like 74hc151 and mod. The circuit but refuesd.

Comment: Who is your doctor, your teacher? If so, why don't you ask the doctor how the circuit is supposed to be operated? -- A multiplexer like 74hc151 does the exact same thing. -- Who did the circuit, and who refused it? -- Yes, you can use an analog input to read two switches at the same time, but this would be a completely different circuit. -- Well, StackOverflow is not a forum, and the comment area is not a messenger chat. You might want to edit your question and clarify the issue. Include all relevant information, please.